# How to launch mobile browser from a webpage in an app?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, mobile

I am working on a mobile website that is inside of an app.  I have no access to the app its self.  There are several links that my client would like to launch from the website in the app and open up in the mobile browser.  Is there a way to do this? Any help would be super appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify what platform you want the answer for?

Comment: Sorry, I need it to work of iOS and Android.

Comment: Ok, in my answer I put both.

Comment: If an answer worked for you, could you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I couldn't tell what platform you wanted it for so here's the solution for both of the platforms you tagged.
On Android you can use this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://urlhere.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

On iOS you can use this (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://urlhere.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Android, but on iOS you would need access the the applications's source code to be able to override

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

if the requested URL should be opened in MobileSafari.

Answer (score 0):

"If you only need to know which device your viewer is using you can use server-side detection like handsetdetection.
The advantage with server side detection is that you can use a different template or layout based on the device."